# Where can I change htdocs redirect on Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, vps

I have a domain delegated to IP address of certain VPS. Someone has configured it already, because when you access the server from http it redirects you to `domain.com/shop`.

Question is, where can I change this redirect? So that instead it would redirect to, say, `domain.com/website`.

`var/www` which is the parent dir of `/shop` doesn't have any `.htaccess` file
`etc/apache2/apache2.conf` says nothing about `/shop` redirect neither.
I have even made a search in file contents looking for `shop` phrase, but it found nothing.

Web server version is: Apache 2.2.16
System: Debian 6.0.2

Comment: httpd.conf, .htaccess, server-side code (e.g. php). lots of places where a redirect can b eput. you'll have to look for it.

Comment: server-side code - of course, I've forgotten about that possibility, there was a nasty header redirect hidden in `var/www/index.php`